# Messages from exchange server 2003 are deleted after configuring outlook 2007 as personal folder

Tags: outlook

I have configured my exchange server to outlook but after configuration all the emails from server gone missing. Then only i found that outlook configured as personal folder.

Is there a way to restore my messages in server.

Also if I imported the .pst file to exchange will the sent items will be disappeared/deleted.

Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you configured a POP3 account and it pulled all of your email off the server.

Configure an Exchange account and drag your emails from the Personal Folders back over to the server inbox. Disable auto Send/Receive while you do this or the POP3 account will just pull them back off again when it next receives.